# How to search globally without replacing?

Tags: regex, bash, perl

For some reason this regex

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]\{([^\}]*)/g' test.tex
```

doesn't search globally when I give it

```
\centerline{\includegraphics[height=70mm]{FIGS/plotTangKurve3}\includegraphics[height=70mm]{FIGS/plotTangKurve2}\includegraphics[height=70mm]{FIGS/plotTangKurve1}}
\centerline{\includegraphics[height=70mm]{FIGS/plotTangKurve3}\includegraphics[height=70mm]{FIGS/plotTangKurve2}\includegraphics[height=70mm]{FIGS/plotTangKurve1}}
```

It only outputs

```
FIGS/plotTangKurve3
FIGS/plotTangKurve3
```

What I was hoping to get was

```
FIGS/plotTangKurve3
FIGS/plotTangKurve2
FIGS/plotTangKurve1
FIGS/plotTangKurve3
FIGS/plotTangKurve2
FIGS/plotTangKurve1
```

**Question**

Can anyone see why that is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to do `while` instead of `if`.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-matching

The `/g` does global matching, but what that means is that each successive match returns a new value. Because you use `if`, you only evaluate the regular expression once and never try the subsequent potential matches. If you use `while` there instead, you'll re-evaluate it until it fails.

In other words:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while /\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]\{([^\}]*)/g' test.tex
```

That gives me the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` only refers to (at most) one match. One way to fix this is to capture and print all of the matches on each line:

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n" for /\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]\{([^\}]*)/g'
```

or

```
perl -nE 'say for /\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]\{([^\}]*)/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

To search some text, better you use `grep` with `PCRE` option:

```
grep -oP '\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]{\K[^{}]+' file

FIGS/plotTangKurve3
FIGS/plotTangKurve2
FIGS/plotTangKurve1
FIGS/plotTangKurve3
FIGS/plotTangKurve2
FIGS/plotTangKurve1
```

`\K` is used for resetting matched information.